# WordPress get_terms not outputting URL

Tags: php, wordpress

I've got the following PHP code that I'm using to output a list of all custom taxonomy values, then group them into alphabetical order by first letter. This is working fine, except that the URL isn't being outputted. Anyone able to help?

```
<?php
$list = '';
$tags = get_terms( 'film-categories' );
$groups = array();
if( $tags && is_array( $tags ) ) {
    foreach( $tags as $tag ) {
        $first_letter = strtoupper( $tag->name[0] );
        $groups[ $first_letter ][] = $tag;
    }
    if( !empty( $groups ) ) {
        foreach( $groups as $letter => $tags ) {
            $list .= '<div class="cat-group"><h3>' . apply_filters( 'the_title', $letter ) . '</h3>';
            $list .= '<ul>';
            foreach( $tags as $tag ) {
                $url = esc_attr( get_tag_link( $tag->term_id ) );
                $name = apply_filters( 'the_title', $tag->name );
                $list .= '<li><a href="' . $url . '">' . $name . '</a></li>';
            }
            $list .= '</ul></div>';
        }
    }
} else $list .= '<p>Sorry, but no tags were found</p>';

echo $list;

?>
```

Comment: Try to `echo` the `$tag->term_id` variable - what's the output of it?

Comment: It just displays 15. The post ID of the page that has the above code in its template is 5, so I don't think that's the problem. (The post with ID 15 is completely unrelated.)

Comment: Please replace that line as I suggest in my answer - tell me if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid you've confused.
According to your second line - you're fetching terms of custom tax and not tags.
`$tags = get_terms( 'film-categories' );`

Therefore , any function related to `tags` won't work correctly.
In order to get the url of the **term** use the [get_term_link()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_link) function.

Just replace the current line with:

```
$url = esc_attr( get_term_link( $tag ) );
```

Should work.

Comment: That's great, thank you. Yes, I was confused in my first comment.

Comment: I'd tried changing that before, but I'd left the $tag part as $tag->term_id. Thanks again.

Comment: WP can be confusing , anytime I'm not sure in something I'm going to the `codex` (docs)